# Dimming a constant current LED after the LED Driver?

Tags: led, esp32, dimmer

I want to get a constant current LED tube. This particular model is made by *toggled*.  And I would like to hijack it and place some sort of a dimming device  AFTER the LED driver and before the LED strip (between the LED driver  and LED). I would then control the device with an ESP32.

With  traditional constant voltage LEDs, I would use a MOSFET for this.  However, using a MOSFET would control the voltage and not the current.  Is this some other transistor that would allow me to do what I'm looking  for?

Again, I would like to control the DC part of the circuit and not the AC 110v part.

Would a BJT transistor after the LED driver work? Excuse my very little knowledge of electronics. But shouldn't this be able to control the current?

Comment: You need to provide datasheets for the LED driver and LED strip.

Comment: It will probably not be easy. Some CC drivers would accept a short on the output and happily go back to the Vf of your LEDs, but most don’t. You don’t have access to any dim or enable pin on the driver?

Comment: Reverse engineering the driver would normally be the first step, but if you don't have a lot of electronics experience, pulling apart a mains power supply isn't the safest thing to do.  Strongly consider learning on low voltage devices, then once you have a lot more knowledge about electronics come back to the dangerous stuff.

Comment: I don't have the datasheets sadly since it's a finished commercial product. 


Winny, I'm not sure, the light bulb says that it's a dimmable tube. But it's for putting a dimmer BEFORE the LEDs. I'm not sure if there's something that I can do within the LED driver. I can break one apart and send a picture.

user1850479, I know enough about electricity to not get electrocuted, so I'm safe. I don't know enough about electronics to do what I'm want to do. I was hoping someone would shine here for that.

Comment: simplest option would be to replace the driver with one you feel capable of controlling. if you must mod, you need to trick the current feedback on the CC driver, which is almost always a shunt resistor. I can't speak to the particular schematic, but often you can inject a small voltage into the driver chip's feedback pin to make it think that more current is being consumed, thus dimming the light.

Answer (score 1):

This ambitious little project takes more to explain how to design this with all the internal workings unknown to the existing design.

I see the "toggled" LED Tubes are now wirelessly, dimmable and have a mobile App.   https://toggled.com/products/toggled-iq/app/

If you wish to work with electronics, it is essential to learn how to read schematics, bias transistors, look-up and read datasheets/specs then understand them.  The quickest way is often with a mentor and scope and reverse-engineer many products to see the signals on a scope and schematic to see how they work.  I have some learning modules in my profile.

I expect you to follow your interests and work hard at it. It does get easier, but it takes time.

Comment: Is there no shortcut to this? I understand that with constant voltage LEDs I can do this with a MOSFET. And I already did this, is there no component that would replace the MOSFET but would control current instead of voltage? Then basically apply a PWM signal?

Comment: if you control the voltage to an LED, you control (limit) the current.

Comment: No that didn't work. It turned into a strobe light, flashing, instead of dimming.

Comment: We have no idea what you are doing